# UpdatePanel not updating on imagebutton click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, imagebutton

I am creating a web page with SEVERAL `updatepanels` nested in ONE parent `updatepanel`. I have defined all of the triggers that are needed to let certain controls update controls that are in other `updatepanels`,I have set every `updatepanel`'s `updatemode` to `conditional` and the property `childrenastriggers` to `false`, and almost everything is working accordingly. But I am stumbling on one `imagebutton_Click` event: when I click the `imagebutton`, it calls the event, but does not update a single `updatepanel`, though I have several other `imagebuttons` in the same `updatepanel` that update their `updatepanels` just fine.

Now this could just be the task of the `imagebutton` that is causing the problem:

- The `imagebutton` starts a timer
- The `imagebutton` adds a predefined table with data in another `updatepanel`.
- The `imagebutton` activated a timer object

Possible already tried solutions:
  - I have tried to set the `causesvalidation` to `false` (property of the `imagebutton`)
  - I have tried to use `myscriptmanager.registerASyncPostBack(imagebutton)`

The code behind my button(though its not really something out of the ordinary) :

```
protected void imbformulier_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        imbFormulier.Visible = false;
        imbGebruikers.Visible = false;
        imbModellen.Visible = false;
        pnlGegevens1.Visible = false;
        pnlGegevens2.Visible = true;
        pnlNavigatie.Visible = true;
        pnlEvaluatie.Visible = true;


        //kijken welk formulier moet ingevuld worden adhv de ddl's en dit meegeven aan de zelfgemaakte klasse

        List<EvaluatieFormulier> mijnformulieren = (List<EvaluatieFormulier>)Session["mijnformulieren"];
        IEnumerator<EvaluatieFormulier> enumerator = mijnformulieren.GetEnumerator();
        EvaluatieFormulier meetegeven = new EvaluatieFormulier();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (((enumerator.Current.GebruikergeevalueerdID == ddlGebruikers.SelectedValue) && (enumerator.Current.ModelID == Convert.ToInt32(ddlModellen.SelectedValue))))
            {
                meetegeven = enumerator.Current;
                //Eventueel tekst veranderen als er al was gewerkt aan een bepaalde evaluatie
                if (meetegeven.Tijdaangewerkt == 0)
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = "Evaluatie gestart van " + ddlGebruikers.SelectedItem.Text;
                    lblDatum.Text = "Evaluatie begonnen op: "+  DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d/M/yyyy") + "(Vandaag)" ;
                    //updaten in database
                    Session["aantalminutenaangewerkt"] = 0;
                    Session["aantalsecondenaangewerkt"] = 0;
                    timTijdAanGewerkt.Enabled = true;
                    lblTijd.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = "Evaluatie verdergezet van " + ddlGebruikers.SelectedItem.Text;
                    lblDatum.Text = "Evaluatie laatst gewijzigd : " + meetegeven.Tijdingevuld.ToString();
                    Session["aantalminutenaangewerkt"] = meetegeven.Tijdaangewerkt;
                    Session["aantalsecondenaangewerkt"] = 0;
                    timTijdAanGewerkt.Enabled = true;
                    lblTijd.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }


        Evaluatieform formulier = new Evaluatieform(meetegeven);
        pnlEvaluatie.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(formulier.EvaluatiePanel);
        Session["formulier"] = formulier;

        if (formulier.evaluatiemodel.Domeins.Count > 4)
        {
            imbVorige.Visible = false;
            imbvolgende.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            imbVorige.Visible = false;
            imbVorige.Visible = false;
            imbvalideren.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, after looking at every aspect, It seems that I just needed to have all of the seperate updatepanel on one page in one big parent updatepanel(which I thought it was in when I posted this "--, change updatemode to conditional and define my triggers.